# QWebEngine header issue

Tags: header, qwebenginepage

Using QWebEnginePage to download web pages. Works very well but sometimes it doesn't work with certain URLs and appears to be a header issue. I can't figure out what headers to send to not get this error.

Header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QWebEnginePage *p;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
protected slots:
    void getHtml(bool s);
    void textChanged();

signals:


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Source

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QWebEngineSettings>
#include <QWebEngineHttpRequest>

QWebEngineHttpRequest httpR;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    p = new QWebEnginePage(this);
    httpR.setHeader("Location", "absoluteURI");
    httpR.setUrl(QUrl("https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AIPT/history?period1=1238597365&period2=1554130165&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"));
    p->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::AutoLoadImages, false);
    p->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    connect(p, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(getHtml(bool)));
    p->load(httpR);

}


QString html = "";
void MainWindow::getHtml(bool s){
   p->toHtml(
       [this](QString result) {
           html=result;
           this->textChanged();
           qDebug()<<httpR.headers();
    });
}

void MainWindow::textChanged(){
    qDebug()<<html.size();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
}
```

Error message:

> js: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'.
>
> js: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'.
>
> 860801 
>   QVector("Location") 
>   js: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy
>   directive 'disown-opener'.
>
> js: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'.
>
> js: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'.
>
> js: The resource
>   https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190327/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds
>   from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it
>   has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out. It appears to fix the *"Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'"* error you would have to incorporate the html tag attribute *"rel=noopener"* in each link tag. However since I want to download html webpages from other sources it would be a bit hard to change each link.

Instead after some trial and error I found that this header *"Upgrade: websocket"* which fixed the issue.